# Sailsjs no CSS in EJS template

Tags: css, node.js, ejs, sails.js

I'm trying to render a template using:

```
res.render('template', data, function(err, html) {
...
});
```

In the template I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
```

And it's not working (checking it with a red background).

The same markup works in pages that depend on views/layout.ejs, that is using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
```

How can I solve this (add style.css to the ejs file) ?

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Link tag [can be placed in the `<head>` section only](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp), so you will probably have to put it in a separate layout or disable the layout and put the whole HTML with the `<head>` tag containing style link tags in your view.

Comment: It is in a head tag, and the placement works, because bootstrap is also included (from a cdn) and works.

Comment: Could you post the HTML source of your page from browser?

Comment: Added it to the question.

Comment: So, where do you place your `style.css`? Can you see it at `http://your.host/styles/style.css` after Sails are lifted?

Comment: So, it should be loaded, right (check in Firebug/DevTools to make sure it's being loaded)? Then the problem may be only in styles. Post your CSS if you wish.

Comment: The CSS file works on other pages, so it's ok. I will try to do this with ejs partials and come back with an answer :).